# Automate Version Control Configuration Management

Tags: svn, version-control, enterprise-architect

I would like to automate the process of configuring EA with version control. (Project -> Version Control -> Version Control Settings window)

I've found instructions to update some registry entries which keeps this data:

1. Set the unique ID in %APPDATA%\SPARX_Systems\EA\paths.txt
2. Set the svn path in registry
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SPARX Systems\EA400\EA\Options\VC_SVNExePath
3. svn Timeout in registry (VC_TIMEOUT)
4. Set the configuration in VCConfigs entry.

However, something is missing and it doesn't work.
I suppose I have to update other registries or database entries, but which?

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve, and what exactly isn't working?

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't enough for people to go on. What isn't happening that you expect to happen? What error messages do you get?

Comment: @Uffe, The local path is exist, the configuration definition in registry is exist, but the new configuration still does not exist in the list of the configuration in the version control settings window. In case the configuration was declared already on another machine, and I deploy the model to a new machines, the actions above does not affect the configuration and it still "Requires Configuration". Thanks.

Comment: @alroc, The local path is exist, the configuration definition in registry is exist, but the new configuration still does not exist in the list of the configuration in the version control settings window. In case the configuration was declared already on another machine, and I deploy the model to a new machines, the actions above does not affect the configuration and it still "Requires Configuration". Thanks.

Comment: Edit that into the original post, please don't make people try to read comments just to get the full story.